# Is there a way to apply a css style to a specific column of primefaces datatable which was created dynamically?

Tags: html, css, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to apply `text-align="right"` to all the cells of a column 'Amount' that contains monetary values like *$4.01* etc. As the table is created dynamically, there is no unique `styleClass` or `id` or any attribute in the rendered td cells which I can use as css selector. CSS has no selectors that supports matching td innerText or apply style on a column of a table by column's headerText. Please let me know if there is a tweak to make it happen. I have jquery imported in my xhtml files but I don't know if I can use jquery selector for the above said requirement as I do not have any .js files in my project.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: cant you target it using only tags: table > tr > td:nth-child(amount_col_no) ..... ?

Comment: When you say that the table was created dynamically, do you mean it was created programmatically in the backing bean? Or are the columns created dynamically with a ui:repreat or something like that? Please add some code

Comment: It was created dynamically with a backing bean programatically.

Comment: Can't you add a styleclass in the place where you create your columns? ie.:       Column column = new Column();
        column.setStyleClass("styleClass");